# Why doesn't setDT have any effect in this case?

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the following code

```
library(data.table) # 1.9.2
x <- data.frame(letters[1:2]) 
setDT(x) 
class(x)
## [1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

Which is an expected result. Now if I run

```
x <- letters[1:2]
setDT(data.frame(x)) 
class(x) 
## [1] "character"
```

The `class` of `x` remained unchanged for some reason.

One possibility is that `setDT` changes only the classes of objects in the global environment, so I've tried

```
x <- data.frame(letters[1:2]) 
ftest <- function(x) setDT(x) 
ftest(x) 
class(x) 
##[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

Seems like `setDT` don't care much about the environment of an object in order to change its class.

So what's causing the above behaviour? Is it just a bug or there is some common sense behind it?

Comment: Why do you expect, that `x`' class in `setDT(data.frame(x))` would be changed to a `data.table`? `setDT` does basically the same as às.data.table` but avoids a lot of copying stuff, which makes it faster on large data.

Comment: @Beasterfield I expect it do something. If not change the `x`, then create a new object. Otherwise it should trough an error or at least a warning that it actually didn't do anything IMO. For example, if you''ll have `x <- factor(c("1","2")); x <- as.numeric(as.character(x))`, `setDT` is supposed to play the `as.numeric` role in this example

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I think the issue is that in setDT(data.frame(x)), data.frame copies x into a new data.frame object, so the setDT does not see the original x, and can thus not alter the original x.

Comment: @DouglasClark, that what I was thinking too, but if `setDT` can't alter it, shouldn't it at least through an error or warning. I mean, what does it actually do when it can't alter the object? Doesn't it conflict with it's purpose?

Comment: My feeling is the `setDT(x)` should give an error if `x` is not a simple name, in the same way that `<-` if you try and assign to something that you can't `(1 + 4) <- 2`

Comment: @hadley, that was exactly my question in my first comment

Comment: @DavidArenburg Right, but `setDT()` also plays the role of `<-`.

Comment: @hadley, yes, that what I meant in my comment, this is why I wrote `x <- ` again. Should have clear that out probably. I've also discussed that with @Arun in [R public](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17382996#17382996) but it seems like he doesn't agree it should behave that way

Comment: And I agree with Arun too.

Comment: If you look at `str(setDT(data.frame(x)))`, you see that setDT invisibly returns the intended data.table object, which disappears because it is not assigned to anything. It is not an error.

Comment: @DouglasClark, yes I know that. The problem i that (as hadley an me already mentioned) `setDT` not only sets a class, but also operates as `<-`. And if it has nowhere to assign, it should have throughn an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setDT` changes the `data.frame` and returns it invisibly. Since you don't save this `data.frame`, it is lost. All you need to do is somehow save the `data.frame`, so that the `data.table` is also saved. E.g.

```
setDT(y <- data.frame(x)) 
class(y)
## [1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

or

```
z <- setDT(data.frame(x))
class(z)
## [1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

Comment: +1 too. `setDT` changes by reference the data it is passed, whether that is named (i.e. bound to a symbol) or not. One other use is in compound expressions before the result is assigned; e.g. `ans = setDT(<something that returns data.frame>)[where, select|update, by]`