# Sub-assign by reference on vector in R

Tags: r, data.table, r6

Can I use sub-assign by reference on atomic vectors somehow?
Of course without wrapping it in 1 column data.table to use `:=`.

```
library(data.table)
N <- 5e7
x <- sample(letters, N, TRUE)
X <- data.table(x = x)
upd_i <- sample(N, 1L, FALSE)
system.time(x[upd_i] <- NA_character_)
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.11    0.06    0.17 
system.time(X[upd_i, x := NA_character_])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.00    0.00    0.03
```

If R6 can help on that I'm open for R6 solution as it is one of my dep already.
I've already checked that `<-` inside `R6` object still makes copy: [gist](https://gist.github.com/jangorecki/3ee84cb9648053cdacd5).

Comment: Interesting. never heard of R6. Looks exciting.

Comment: @DavidArenburg R6 is IMO the best reference class and OOP tool in R. Definitely worth to learn and easy to learn.

Comment: I'm guessing you can modify by reference with Rcpp. Google yielded: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11300048/1191259 Ari's answer in question linked there has a simple function for it that outperforms the rest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most recent R versions (3.1-3.1.2+ or so), assignment to a vector does not copy. You will not see that by running OP's code though, and the reason for that is the following. Because you reuse `x` and assign it to some other object, R is not notified that `x` is copied at that point, and has to assume that it won't be (in the particular case above, I think it'll be good to change it in `data.table::data.table` and notify R that a copy has been made, but that's a separate issue - `data.frame` suffers from same issue), and because of that it copies `x` on first use. If you change the order of the commands a bit, you'd see no difference:

```
N <- 5e7
x <- sample(letters, N, TRUE)
upd_i <- sample(N, 1L, FALSE)
# no copy here:
system.time(x[upd_i] <- NA_character_)
#   user  system elapsed 
#      0       0       0 
X <- data.table(x = x)
system.time(X[upd_i, x := NA_character_])
#   user  system elapsed 
#      0       0       0 

# but now R will copy:
system.time(x[upd_i] <- NA_character_)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.28    0.08    0.36
```

---

(old answer, mostly left as a curiosity)

You actually can use the `data.table` `:=` operator to modify your vector in place (I think you need R version 3.1+ to avoid the copy in `list`):

```
modify.vector = function (v, idx, value) setDT(list(v))[idx, V1 := value]

v = 1:5
address(v)
#[1] "000000002CC7AC48"

modify.vector(v, 4, 10)
v
#[1]  1  2  3 10  5

address(v)
#[1] "000000002CC7AC48"
```

Comment: Cannot agree more on the solution, I benchmark it and it is super fast. @eddi I think it is a good feature for PR.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why this works... I.e., if you do `res <- setDT(list(v))[4, V1 := 10]` you will get back a `data.table` rather a vector. I've asked once a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426164/why-doesnt-setdt-have-any-effect-in-this-case) and was told by R-devs that this shouldn't work

Comment: @DavidArenburg the reason why it works is that neither `list` nor `setDT` copy the underlying data. They do create new objects though that are wrapping the data, so that `res` is new object, but which contains the original vector inside.

Comment: @jangorecki hmm, while this answer probably only works for R 3.1+, it's actually outdated for R 3.1+, as I'm pretty sure no extra copies are made for regular vector assignment now, i.e. `v[4] = 20` does not make any unnecessary copies

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by @Frank, it's possible to do this using `Rcpp`. Here's a version including a macro inspired by Rcpp's `dispatch.h` which handles all atomic vector types:

mod_vector.cpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

template <int RTYPE>
Vector<RTYPE> mod_vector_impl(Vector<RTYPE> x, IntegerVector i, Vector<RTYPE> value) {
  if (i.size() != value.size()) {
    stop("i and value must have same length.");
  }
  for (int a = 0; a < i.size(); a++) {
    x[i[a] - 1] = value[a];
  }
  return x;
}

#define __MV_HANDLE_CASE__(__RTYPE__) case __RTYPE__ : return mod_vector_impl(Vector<__RTYPE__>(x), i, Vector<__RTYPE__>(value));

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP mod_vector(SEXP x, IntegerVector i, SEXP value) {
  switch(TYPEOF(x)) {
    __MV_HANDLE_CASE__(INTSXP)
    __MV_HANDLE_CASE__(REALSXP)
    __MV_HANDLE_CASE__(RAWSXP)
    __MV_HANDLE_CASE__(LGLSXP)
    __MV_HANDLE_CASE__(CPLXSXP)
    __MV_HANDLE_CASE__(STRSXP)
    __MV_HANDLE_CASE__(VECSXP)
    __MV_HANDLE_CASE__(EXPRSXP)
  }
  stop("Not supported.");
  return x;
}
```

Example:

```
x <- 1:20
address(x)
#[1] "0x564e7e8"
mod_vector(x, 4:5, 12:13)
# [1]  1  2  3 12 13  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
address(x)
#[1] "0x564e7e8"
```

Comparison with base and data.table methods. It can be seen it's a lot faster:

```
x <- 1:2e7
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(mod_vector(x, 4:5, 12:13), x[4:5] <- 12:13, modify.vector(x, 4:5, 12:13))
#Unit: microseconds
#                         expr     min       lq        mean    median         uq
#    mod_vector(x, 4:5, 12:13)   5.967   7.3480    15.05259     9.718    21.0135
#              x[4:5] <- 12:13   2.953   5.3610 45722.61334 48122.996 52623.1505
# modify.vector(x, 4:5, 12:13) 954.577 988.7785  1177.17925  1021.380  1361.1210
#        max neval
#     58.463   100
# 126978.146   100
#   1559.985   100
```