# Logical manipulation of lists in R

Tags: r

I have some R that is, for example:

```
x<-c(-3,1,-5,7,-10)
y<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I want to check the elements of x against some condition, i.e. <0, and if true, manipulate y based on that.

For example, if my logical check was x<0, then elements [0],[2],[4] of y would be modified, i.e.:

```
print(y)
y=[0,2,0,3,0]
```

I've googled around a bit and cant find anything that does it element-wise. I'm sure that is a failing of google-fu, but help much appreciated.

Comment: In R, indexing starts at 1. You can try `y[x < 0] <- 0`. Your desired output also seems off. Are you looking for `y=[0,2,0,4,0]`?

Comment: I think there is a mistake. The expected output should probably be `0 2 0 4 0`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I mean elements 1 3 and 5, if R counts from 1.

Comment: Your suggested method works well in the test case above, but it doesnt seem to be working in my script. Will investigate further, must be a screw up by me.

Comment: I found the problem. I was logically checking if it was <-5, so I was doing y[x<-5]... which of course is an assignment operator. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For instance this would add 1 to those values.

```
y[x < 0] <- y[x < 0] + 1
```

Assuming you want to keep all of the Y elements:

```
y <- ifelse(x < 0, 0, y)
```

Comment: My answer is very similar to @Pierre Lafortune, notably his is far more elegant. Lots of ways to get work done in R! Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. I was logically checking against -5, i.e. y[x<-5]... Dumb. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

```
y[x < 0] <- 0
y
#[1] 0 2 0 4 0
```

Indexing starts at 1 in R. We can subset `y` by the logical index of `x < 0`. One strength of R is the ability to subset by names, booleans, and numbers.

These two functions return the same output `y[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)]` and `y[c(1,3,5)]`. The function attempts to determine which type of subsetting you are doing.

The third case for subsetting can't be used in this example because `y` doesn't have names. But if we named the vector, we can subset that way too.

```
names(y) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
y[c("A", "C", "E")]
```

---

It also appears that you were slowed down by spacing and assignment operators. It is unique to R, but `<-` is similar to `=`.

```
x<-5
```

In this case, `<-` gets priority in the order of operations and is equivalent to `x = 5`, not `x < -5`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. I was logically checking against -5, i.e. y[x<-5]... Dumb. Thanks!

Comment: Yep. Brackets fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the way boolian variables are implemented, you can use them in arithmetic as if they are 0 or 1, and therefore for your example you can use:

```
y*(x>=0)
[1] 0 2 0 4 0
```

For a more general purpose method, the `replace` function exists:

```
replace(y,x<0,0)
[1] 0 2 0 4 0
```

Comment: This first one has the advantage of having no copies made.  And I imagine it's also faster.

Comment: @RichardScriven If you want to get all benchmarky about it, this operation does replacement by reference: `library(data.table); setDT(list(y))[x<0, V1 := 0]` (as far as I can tell, looking at `address` before and after). Taken from eddi's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344192/sub-assign-by-reference-on-vector-in-r

Comment: Not too concerned about it.  But I do like this first answer.  With all the code golf going on around here I figured this would get more votes.