# How to use chaining with by reference in j operator (:=) to affect the underlying table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following piece piece of code as a test here

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table::data.table(letters = sample(LETTERS,200,replace = TRUE),numbers = sample(1:1000,200,replace = TRUE))
sortcols <- c("letters","numbers")
setkeyv(dt,sortcols)
dt
#         letters numbers
#  1:       A     258
#  2:       A     400
#  3:       A     429
#  4:       A     496
#  5:       B      72
# ---                
#196:       Z     142
#197:       Z     462
#198:       Z     583
#199:       Z     665
#200:       Z     954
dt[letters=="A"][,numbers := numbers/2]
dt2 <- dt[letters=="A"][,numbers := numbers/2]

dt[letters=="A"]
#       letters numbers
#1:       A     258
#2:       A     400
#3:       A     429
#4:       A     496


dt2
#       letters numbers
#1:       A   129.0
#2:       A   200.0
#3:       A   214.5
#4:       A   248.0
```

What I am trying to understand here is

1. Why does by reference operator := here used like

> dt[letters=="A"][,numbers := numbers/2]

does not affect the underlying data table dt (and the numbers column remains the same for all letters=="A") whereas when I make a copy of it as dt2, it is reflected in the copied result (i.e., numbers column in dt2 has been divided by 2 for all letters=="A", which was the original intent of the code). Isnt the function of by reference operator, :=, to affect the underlying data table without making copies?

2. Is it possible to not make a copy of the data table and still use chaining and := for what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Re 1- You are basically operating on a new data.table `dt[letters=="A"]` which doesn't exist anywhere, hence if you are not saving it somewhere, your changes will be lost (this is similar to a [question I've asked in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426164/why-doesnt-setdt-have-any-effect-in-this-case)). Re 2- it is not clear why would you need this, why can't you do `dt[letters=="A" ,numbers := numbers/2]`? And yes, you can chain `:=` but not on a new subseted data like you've created, but on the original one, e.g. `dt[, x := 1][, y := x * 3]` will modify `dt` in place.

Comment: I'd recommend setting `options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)` while you're getting used to the syntax. Then you'll see that your way says "Assigning to all 4 rows" while David's says "Assigning to 4 row subset of 200 rows". The startup messages shown when you first type `library(data.table)` provide good guidance on the syntax.